# Visual Basic - RichTextBox with multiple links

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, richtextbox

I'm sure I will feel stupid when I get an answer, but it's been a while since I programmed.

I am looking at having a form with a rich text box that will have multiple lines of text and among that text it will have two or more groups of words highlighted that will be links that can be clicked (not URLs). I got it working with one link. But when I try to extend it to two link the second link does not show.

This is the Single Link version and works fine, When I click the link, I get on the console the text I clicked on.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim linktarget As String = ""
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        Dim lnk1 As New LinkLabel
        CreateLink(lnk1, "This is the Target", "Description of Link")
        txtBox.Controls.Add(lnk1)



    End Sub

    Public Sub CreateLink(lnk As LinkLabel, linkTarget As String, linkText As String)
        lnk.LinkColor = Color.Blue
        Dim lk As LinkLabel.Link = lnk.Links.Add(0, linkText.Length, linkTarget)
        lnk.Text = linkText
        AddHandler lnk.LinkClicked, AddressOf LinkClicked
    End Sub


    Private Sub LinkClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'send link to the browser
        Console.WriteLine(sender.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I add the second link as follows There is no change I only get one link

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        Dim lnk1 As New LinkLabel
        CreateLink(lnk1, "This is the Target", "Description of Link")
        txtBox.Controls.Add(lnk1)

        Dim lnk2 As New LinkLabel
        CreateLink(lnk2, "Another Target", "Description of 2nd Link")
        txtBox.Controls.Add(lnk2)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link controls are stacked on each other : specify location, and incidentally set autosize true to avoid a truncated display.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim lnk1 As New LinkLabel
        CreateLink(lnk1, "This is the Target", "Description of Link")
        lnk1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        lnk1.AutoSize = True
        TxtBox.Controls.Add(lnk1)

        Dim lnk2 As New LinkLabel
        CreateLink(lnk2, "Another Target", "Description of 2nd Link")
        lnk2.Location = New Point(10, 30)
        lnk2.AutoSize = True
        TxtBox.Controls.Add(lnk2)
end sub
```